# App posting to user wall - Graph API vs Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Granted there is a lot of info on how to accomplish a lot of different things on Facebook.  Resources are not what is missing, but I am missing some sort of information.  I feel there is confusion with the `Open Graph` and `Graph API`.

I am writing an app that will post a message to a users wall.

1. User grants access to the app
2. App gathers this user information
3. Program (in this case Java) posts to users wall

In theory this is simple enough.

To get #3 to work, I've used the `Graph API` [publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) call.  Works great.

But after getting all of this to work, I see on the same page that the `/PROFILE_ID/feed` call states:

> Publish a new post on the given profile's feed/wall. **Note that this
>   feature will be removed soon.**

*Great!*  I've tried finding the equivalent using the Open Graph, but cannot seem to find anything similar.  I've seen that for an app to post to a wall without user authorization (I only want the user to authorize the app once, then the app can post many times - the user cannot be involved in every post) it had to use `Action` and `Objects`, but only Facebook pre-defined...  Can this still be done via `HTTP request`?

To top off on the confusion, in the `Open Graph` advanced topics [How-To: Use an app Access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/publishing-with-app-token/) it refers back to use

```
curl -X POST \
  -F 'message=Post%20with%20app%20access%20token' \
  -F 'access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/4804827/feed
```

Which is back to the original method I found using the `Graph API` that **will be removed soon**.

I wish someone could help me make sense of this.  I don't need code.  There is too many posts already with just code and a bug fix.  I beleive I need understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with your request 3: Program (in this case Java) posts to users wall

To accomplish this 
1. you need to know what you are going to post on user's wall.

1. As per [Facebook-Opengraph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/), this information is segregated as user + action + object.
2. Now you need to define what are the actions you wanted. Refer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/)
3. Then define your [objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/)
4. Publish your story or message on to the user's wall.